# Posting questions from answers written in Open Office

Tags: feature-request, answers

I have written a very nice answer to a question in Open Office and would now like to post it but the copy paste function does not work properly. I'm having problems with inserting tables. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for tables in Markdown. What you can do is screen grab an image of the table and add it as a picture.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Sklivvze's answer is probably the best.

Alternatively, answers to this question: [Is there any markdown to create tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables) suggests various hacks for formatting small tables.

You could also format and store the table elsewhere (e.g. an HTML or PDF page) and post a link to it; but that's no so good because it's better if answers are self-contained, to protect against 'link-rot'.